# jQuery Not Working from within a table?

Tags: jquery, forms, html-table

I've been working on a simple product order form that takes quantities, calculates a line total and then adds each line total to form a grand total.

I'm using jQuery to perform the calculations and everything works beautifully, except when the form is formatted within a table.

Here's a `jsFiddle` -> http://jsfiddle.net/WekLs/

If I just remove the opening table tag everything functions as it should.

```
<table class="twelve">
```

I suspect it has something to do with either `.next()` or `.index()` but I'm not entirely sure.

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your

```
$this.next('.linetotal').val(getPrice(qty, idx));
```

to

```
$this.parents('tr').find('.linetotal').val(getPrice(qty, idx));
```

Answer (score 0):

end your `img` tags properly `<img src="" />`

end your `h5` tags properly `<h5> </h5>` 
...

Edit and review all your HTML markup and you're good to go for new tests

Comment: Thanks a lot for catching those.